# Grouping by column using get() while using a filter does not work in some situations

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table which I want to filter and aggregate where some columns to group by are fixed and some come from function arguments.
This combination yields an error message.

Here is a simple and reproducible example

```
dt <- data.table(A = rnorm(10), 
             B = sample(c("1", "2"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
             C = sample(c("1", "2"), 10, replace = TRUE))
col1 <- "B"

dt[B == "1", mean(A), by = .(get(col1))]      # works
dt[B == "1", mean(A), by = .(C, get(col1))]   # does not work
dt[, mean(A), by = .(C, get(col1))]           # works
dt[B == "1", mean(A), by = c("C", col1)]      # works and returns the intended result
dt[B == "1"][, mean(A), by = .(C, get(col1))] # works and returns the intended result
```

I don't understand why `dt[B == "1", mean(A), by = .(C, get(col1))]` does not work while chaining in `dt[B == "1"][, mean(A), by = .(C, get(col1))]` does.

Comment: `by=c("C", col1)`? Several alternatives are documented in `?data.table`

Comment: I added your suggestion in the code example. I understand that this works as well but I don't understand why `by = .(C, get(col1))` doesn't when there is a filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason could be is because when you define `col1 <- "B"` you are assigning the value`B` to `col1` in the global environment, so the function `get` will look up for `B` which is not defined.

Comment: I think this is happening because, when you define the `data.table` `dt` you are defining `B`, so is like inside the environment of `dt` you have `B`, so when you go `by = .(C, get(col1))` you are defining a list with the variables that can be found in the environment of `dt`. However when you `get(col1)` it will go an look in the global environment the value `B` which is not there.  But, when you go `dt[B == "1"][, mean(A), by = .(C, get(col1))]` the environment for `get` will be the one of `dt[B=="1"]`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It's hard to understand why there are different environments for dt[B == "1"] and dt[]
I guess there is a reason for this buried in the design of data.table. I'll accept your answer

Comment: You are welcome. For more information I will suggest you to go through the 'Details' section in `?data.table` and `?get`.